# Ubuntu 22.04 itself moved from /dev/sda2 to /dev/sda4

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 22.04

My Ubuntu used to be on `/dev/sda2`. I made a 48GB partition for Windows and I installed Windows on it. After installing when I tried to boot into Ubuntu 22.04 it showed the error: `/dev/sda2 unexpected inconsistency manual fsck required`. I thought my Ubuntu was corrupted, but after rebooting the computer a few times it booted into `/dev/sda4`, Ubuntu boots, and it's working fine. I don't know how it went from `/dev/sda2` itself. The main thing is it sometimes boots into sda2 instead of sda4. How do I make it always boot into sda4 for Linux?

My partitions:

`/dev/sda1` efi partition
`/dev/sda2` Microsoft reserved
`/dev/sda3` the partition where Windows was installed
`/dev/sda4` linux filesystem

[image: List of my partitions:]

Comment: You've provided no Ubuntu product/release details; but the partition addresses (sda & number) can change due to BIOS/uEFI config changes or just partition table changes; which is why UUID or unique IDs are used.

Comment: my ubuntu version is 22.04

Comment: When adding additional details; please add them to your question (that is what is answered; this is a Q&A or *Question & Answer* site don't forget - not a forum).  Also be specific as there can be differences with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server vs Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop...  The movement from sda2 to sda4 would be by a person on the machine via setting or partition table change..

Comment: i'll take care of this from the next time. im new to the site

Comment: Something is wrong here, `sda2` is a Microsoft Reserved Partition and should not be Ext4. I don't know how you did that, but it should be fixed. But at the end, this is a Windows problem.

Comment: i dont know but the uuid of both of the partitions are same

Comment: UUIDs are supposed to be *unique* (UNIQUE is in the name!.. Universe Unique ID).. If two partitions have the same Unique ID, then the results are *unknown* as that is a condition the standard & no operating system supports (*it cannot occur except due to operator error such as cloning without changing values*).